# How to get external Logitech Universal Recever to be accepted?

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

Currently running Ventura 13.2.1 on a MacBook Pro 2021.

My work sent me a Mac laptop and I have Windows laptop and to make things easier I bought a KVM switch. On the switch I put a Logitech bluetooth Universal receiver. It works fine with the Windows machine like that but getting the Mac to use the bluetooth receiver is proving to be difficult.

What I have done so far is:

- Put the bluetooth receiver directly on the Mac.
- Used a different bluetooth receiver.

In the case of the bluetooth receivers the same thing happened with both of them, even a 3rd that I found which is this:

- It would come up and ask "Allow accessory to connect?"
- I would say yes.
- It would ask me to press a key on the keyboard of the device. I don't have a bluetooth keyboard, all as I did was plug the receiver in. It tells me that until I identify the device by pressing a key on the keyboard (that I don't have) that the device will not be accepted. I have no choice, I press skip.
- That's the end of that sequence.

It makes no difference whether the receiver is plugged directly into the Mac or on the KVM switch.

- Once this has happened if I unplug the device and plug it back in then nothing happens so the device seems unusable as I hit a dead end of anything happening.
- I look in the bluetooth system settings and see no difference, I was hoping to see a sign of an external bluetooth device but it looks the same as it always does with just the internal bluetooth device.
- I try another universal receiver and the same thing happens. Turn the laptop off and back on again and then replug in the external bluetooth receiver and nothing happens.

I also went to the Logitech website to try and download their software where they just said, "There is no software for this OS" so I guess it's just supposed to be all native to the Mac handling this.

Ultimately I want this to have my bluetooth mouse connected through the KVM switch but so far I have not gotten very far to make this happen because of the Mac.

Comment: The unifying receiver is **not** Bluetooth.  Why didn’t you plug it into the KVM?

Comment: I plugged it into both, KMV first, results the same. One side is bluetooth and the other is USB so it is bluetooth. Perhaps there is a more precise name for it but it adapts between USB and bluetooth whatever you call it.

Comment: That doe not make sense. You plug the adapter into the KVM then connect the KVM ti both computers.

Comment: I don't know what doesn't make sense. The mouse is bluetooth. The adapter is bluetooth. Once the receiver is working with the OS you can connect the mouse to the receiver. Then when you switch the KVM the mouse will will switch between the machines as the KVM switched the USB between the machines. Work with Windows, would work with the Mac if I could get it to acknowledge the receiver but I can't get that first step to work. To remove a variable, I connect the receiver directly to the Mac to get it working but even with removing the KVM from the system it still won't work with the Mac.

Comment: [It’s not BT](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/resource-center/what-is-unifying.html). You connect the KVM to both computers and the mouse and keyboard (unifying receiver) to the KVM. Is there a manual for the KVM?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer/technical  support issue with the KVM and not with Apple or macOS.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought "universal receiver" was some marketing that Logitech wrapped around bluetooth so I learned something. It's their own software although they will almost certainly be using the same hardware as bluetooth, at least that what it looks like when you look up the RF chip.

Comment: That said, ignore the KVM, it's immaterial of my problem which is I can't get Mac to accept the universal receiver, even connected directly, without it asking for a keyboard that I don't have. How do I get it to accept the receiver for my mouse to use with it? The problem is the same without the KVM and accepting that Logitech's universal protocol is different to bluetooth.

Comment: Your Mac has BT built in.  You don’t need that receiver.  Put the mouse in BT mode and pair it to the Mac.

Comment: @Reg Can you include a screenshot of where it tells you that the accessory won't be allowed until you press a key on the keyboard? - The unifying receiver presents itself  to the OS as a keyboard, that's why macOS asks you to identify the keyboard - like it would have if it had been a real keyboard. However, as far as I remember, in the past you could just close that window and have the mouse working perfectly fine.

Comment: @jksoegaard It doesn't come up with that anymore. I'm going to bet that you're right and it's working. In that case my problem would be getting the Mac to choose to use the external Universal receiver over its built-in bluetooth when pairing devices. There's got to be a System Info somewhere that will update when a device is plugged in and pulled out and with luck a place that will show what's connected through that device. I thought it was the bluetooth area under system but maybe there's better ways to see what's going on as I don't see signs of the universal receiver there.

Comment: @Allan It is through the internal BT. I want it through the external UR or an external BT, I don't care which is connected externally, the mouse will still connect to it either way. Then once it is working I could move the UR/BT from the port on the Mac to the KVM and the mouse will switch with the Monitor via the KVM. That can't be done through the internal BT.

Comment: That is not the way any of this works. The mouse is already paired to the UR. There is no need to do what you describe, connect it to the Mac then move it to the KVM.   Where exactly did you obtain this procedure?

Comment: @Alan, 1) the goal is/has/and will always be to have the mouse & monitor switch conveniently, you know, what KVM switches do, so your insistence of connecting to the Mac directly will never work. Why you keep insisting I don't know, it makes no sense.

Comment: 2) The circuit diagrams of UR's that I could find suggest that the mouse is paired to the software in the computer and that the UR is just a conduit for the radio signal. Not what I originally thought would be the case and it kills the idea of putting the UR on the KVM because the mouse will only pair with one device at a time meaning to change to another device, I have to use a switch on the mouse.

Comment: This leaves the solution being to give up on the use of a BT mouse and use a wired USB mouse into to KVM switch. It is not my ideal choice but it satisfies the main goal of conveniently using a KVM switch to swap between two computers. And, it is what I settled on. I should probably close this question but just in case I am wrong about the UR being just a dumb radio signal conduit I'll leave it open for someone who knows for sure otherwise to show that to be the case.